# Powermock - Unable to mock ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: powermock, powermockito

I am unable to mock the ScheduledExcecutorService. Unsure where I am making the mistake. One weird part about the exception is "Cannot find method schedule in Object hierarchy", why is it trying to find method in Object class instead of ScheduledExecutorService?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ScheduledExecutorService.class, GenericCache.class, ConfigurationDAO.class, ScheduledFuture.class })
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class CacheManagerTestCase {

// Fields 

@Mock
private ScheduledExecutorService mockScheduledExecutorService;

@Mock
private ScheduledFuture scheduledFutureMock;


// Within Test method

when(mockScheduledExecutorService
                        .schedule(any(Runnable.class), anyLong(), eq(TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                        .thenReturn(scheduledFutureMock);
```

When running the above code, following exception is thrown

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) schedule were found in the class hierarchy of class java.lang.Object.
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1720)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1745)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getBestMethodCandidate(WhiteboxImpl.java:983)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.findMethodToInvoke(MockGateway.java:317)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.init(MockGateway.java:356)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.<init>(MockGateway.java:307)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:142)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:125)
at CacheManagerTestCase.testPeriodicRefreshPropertyFalse(CacheManagerTestCase.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)



org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at CacheManagerTestCase.testPeriodicRefreshPropertyFalse(CacheManagerTestCase.java:82)
-> at CacheManagerTestCase.testPeriodicRefreshPropertyFalse(CacheManagerTestCase.java:82)
-> at CacheManagerTestCase.testPeriodicRefreshPropertyFalse(CacheManagerTestCase.java:82)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Comment: Side note: why are you using PowerMock here? Mockito should do fine. And: please put up a [mcve]; something that we can just copy/compile/run ourselves. I feel inclined to look into this fail; (as the code looks good on a first glance); but I kinda don't want to invest the time to write down the code to verify your problem.

Comment: @GhostCat you are right. I removed PowerMock from the test class (it was running with PowerMockRunner.class, I changed it to SpringRunner.class) and strangely the TestCase started passing. I still don't understand why that would cause the conflict though.